How to know the distance between points and the center in Netlogo
I want to know the distance between two variables and the center of the map (a bit strange the method but it should work)
My agents have two variables, economic and cultural, that range from -10 to 10. Previously I asked how to graph them, now I need to know how far are those variables from the center. To do so, i thought
ask patch ([economic] of turtles)([cultural] of turtles) [set distancia-agri distancexy 0 0] 

Where economic cultural  and distancia-agri are patch-own variables.
However, this gave me an error: PATCH expected input to be a number but got the list. I need a list, as I want to compare the variables from all turtles. How could I approach this?
Edit:
Just tried this and Didnt work either
ask patches with [pxcor = (map round [economic] of turtles) and pycor = (map round[cultural] of turtles)][set pcolor red]

The red command is just to check if its doing somenting, its not

It's not clear to me how you want to measure the distance between a variable and a coordinate, since a variable itself has no spatial location. What you could measure is the distance between the agent the variable is attributed to and a coordinate.

Why don't you simply use pythagoras to calculate the distance? the distance between 0,0 (the center of the map) and economy/cultural of 5,7 is simply the square root of 25+49. Seems a lot safer than writing code that will produce different results when you increase patch sizes.
